# Python dateparser.parse only returns NoneType object when using AWS EC2 (Running Python 3.7.9)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, datetime, amazon-ec2, dateparser

Running the following simple code works just fine on my local machine running Python 3.7.3, but returns only object type None when running the same file on an AWS EC2 instance running Python 3.7.9. Any thoughts what could be going on? How can I troubleshoot where it is failing? Logging with debug captures nothing. It is not raising an error, the module is treating the date string as if it doesn't recognize a date, whereupon it by design create a NoneType object.

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import dateparser

date1 = '2020-01-01'
date2 = '12/13/2020'
date3 = 'December 15, 2020'
date4 = 'Saturday, Dec 12'
date5 = '12-12-2020'
date1p = dateparser.parse(date1)
date2p = dateparser.parse(date2)
date3p = dateparser.parse(date3)
date4p = dateparser.parse(date4)
date5p = dateparser.parse(date5)
print("Date 1 Original:", date1)
print("Date 1 Parsed:", date1p)
print("Date 2 Original:", date2)
print("Date 2 Parsed:", date2p)
print("Date 3 Original:", date3)
print("Date 3 Parsed:", date3p)
print("Date 4 Original:", date4)
print("Date 4 Parsed:", date4p)
print("Date 5 Original:", date5)
print("Date 5 Parsed:", date5p)
```

Output on local machine running 3.7.3:

```
Date 1 Original: 2020-01-01
Date 1 Parsed: 2020-01-01 00:00:00
Date 2 Original: 12/13/2020
Date 2 Parsed: 2020-12-13 00:00:00
Date 3 Original: December 15, 2020
Date 3 Parsed: 2020-12-15 00:00:00
Date 4 Original: Saturday, Dec 12
Date 4 Parsed: 2020-12-12 00:00:00
Date 5 Original: 12-12-2020
Date 5 Parsed: 2020-12-12 00:00:00
```

Output on EC2 with 3.7.9:

```
Date 1 Original: 2020-01-01
Date 1 Parsed: None
Date 2 Original: 12/13/2020
Date 2 Parsed: None
Date 3 Original: December 15, 2020
Date 3 Parsed: None
Date 4 Original: Saturday, Dec 12
Date 4 Parsed: None
Date 5 Original: 12-12-2020
Date 5 Parsed: None
```

Any ideas? I'm not sure where to even start with troubleshooting.

Comment: What is the `dateparser.__version__` in each environment?  The Python version is not as important.

Comment: Good question. It is 1.0.0 in both environments.

Comment: For reference, the corresponding GitHub issue: https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser/issues/857